# Comparing array and find same data count

Tags: c, algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, arr1[100000], arr2[100000], cnt=0;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr2[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) cnt++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", cnt);
}
```

this is a code to find same data count in arr1 and arr2, a and b is a number of data in arr1 and arr2.

For Example, 3 3 input in first line and
10 
20
30
11
20
30

inputs,

the arr1 is [10, 20, 30], and arr2 is[11, 20, 30] and the same data count is 2. Is there a way to make the algorithm more fast?

Any help would be great! Thank you!

[SOLVED] use binary search

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
{
    if (r >= l)
    {
        int mid = l + (r - l)/2;
        if (arr[mid] == x)  return mid;
        if (arr[mid] > x) return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);
        return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr1[100001], arr2[100001], cnt=0, a, b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < b; i++) scanf("%d", &arr2[i]);

    sort(arr1, arr1+a);
    sort(arr2, arr2+b);

    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        int result = binarySearch(arr1, 0, a, arr2[i]);
        if(result != -1) cnt++;
    }
    printf("%d", cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Removed C++ tag since we're using stdio, scanf etc.

Comment: `Is there a way to make the algorithm more fast?` yes, if the arrays are in sorted order or sort them before finding the count then you can optimize your algorithm.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, cnt=0;
    long long int arr1[100001], arr2[100001];
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) scanf("%lld", &arr1[i]);
    for(int j = 0; j < a; j++) scanf("%lld", &arr2[j]);

    sort(arr1, arr1+a);
    sort(arr2, arr2+a);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]) cnt++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", cnt);
}

@H.S. like this code?

Comment: @itsss: If the arrays are in sorted order no need to iterate from `j = 0` to `j < b` for every `i`. Alternatively, you can use binary search to find an element of `arr2` in `arr1`.

Comment: Research `qsort()` and `bsearch()`

Comment: Can you make the algorithm faster? No. Are there different algorithms that are faster than yours? Yes, too many to list. Some start by sorting one or both lists to speed up searching. Others might build a bitmap from one of the lists to avoid searching altogether.

Comment: @H.S. i used binary search and make algorithm fast. thanks!

Comment: for SO, post the answer as an answer, not in a question edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the answer to this question depends completely upon what are your input constraints. In your case the size of arrays `a` and `b` play the most crucial role.

Now if you were to sort both the arrays the complexity would be O(a*log(a)) or O(b*log(b)) whichever is big. But in your case the complexity is O(a*b).

Now the question is , is your a*b > complexity for sorting. If in general it's not it's better to stick with your previous approach as there are no added overheads, else you can go with sorting and binary search.

**Note :** An algorithm can't be made fast, instead you can use another algorithm  having less time complexity.

I have generally used O() notation just to avoid any further confusions, so bear with me if I am wrong.